# Truffle migrate success but contract address is not displayed

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

I am using testrpc to deploy my contracts. Contract deployment is successful and it also displays the contract address in console when it is deployed.
[image: deployed successful]
But when I try to query from truffle console it throws this error: `Contract has no network configuration for its current network id (5777)`.

[image: Error]

I am clueless. Any help would be much appreciated. I am using Truffle v4.1.0-beta.0 (core: 4.1.0).
Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)

Comment: Odd...are you able to get the transaction hash for the V2 deployment in the console? What happens if you do `ContractV2.at(ADDR)`?

Comment: Yes. When I tried ContractV2.at(ADDR). It displays abi, bytecode and everything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return the the deployed contract from the Promise to have the contract object be injected by Truffle. Example:

```
var Caller = artifacts.require("Caller");
var Callee = artifacts.require("Callee");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Callee).then(function() {
    return deployer.deploy(Caller, Callee.address);
  });
};
```